# What should one use when introducing dialogue, hyphens, en-dashes or em-dashes?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, dashes, em-dashes

I have always use the hyphen when introducing dialogue.

> -I love skating, but I'm not very good at it.

But I have recently been educated about the existence and use of en/em dashes. Now, I think I got a grip on the basics, but I actually didn't find anything on using them as dialogue introductions. So, what is correct, a hyphen, an en dash or an em dash? Here's all of them lined up, in case you haven't seen them all.

-

–

—

Also, a little side question. Is it normal, and acceptable to use hyphens and dashes as dialogue starters? I'm not looking solely for your individual opinions, as that is off-topic, but rather numbers on what the majority prefers.

Comment: Nope. Start the sentence with a Capital Letter. Use "quotes" if you are quoting someone. If you want to divert during the sentence, there are various ways, such a dashes, commas, parentheses. Using a kind of dash to start a sentence looks like a *foible*. However in forums such as this, and in letters etc, you can use bullet points, but avoid making a letter too staccato.

Comment: In English usage, dialog goes in quotation marks (" " or ' '), in preference to preceding dashes.  In other languages such as French, preceding dashes are the norm, as, for example:  *--Qu'est-ce que se passe, dit il* ("What's going on," he said.)

Comment: @tautophile gives a textbook example of English dialogue ("You are correct," she replied.). That’s how I leaned to punctuate dialogue in school.

Comment: I agree that you would normally use quotes. However, if you *had* to use a non-standard symbol (I wouldn't, unless you can provide a good example for it) use an em dash rather than a hyphen or en dash. The latter two have specific uses that don't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article "Quotation mark"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Quotation_dash) (section "Quotation dash"):

> The Unicode standard introduced a separate character U+2015 ― HORIZONTAL BAR to be used as a quotation dash. In general it is **the same length as an em-dash**, and so this is often used instead. The main difference between them is that at least some software will insert a line break after an em dash, but not after a quotation dash.

So from a typographical perspective, the em dash seems to be standard. I agree with what Jason Bassford said in a comment:

> [The hyphen and the en dash] have specific uses that don't apply.

In formats where it is not possible to use an em dash character, a double hyphen is often used as a substitute.

Answer (score 9):

If you must use something other than quotation marks for dialog, here is *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.) 6.91:

> Em dashes are occasionally used instead of quotation marks to set off dialogue (à la writers in some European languages). Each speech starts a new paragraph. No space follows the dash.
>
> —Will he obtain the necessary signatures?
> —Of course he will!

As for the *normal* introduction to dialogue, here is *Chicago* 13.39:

> Direct discourse or dialogue is traditionally enclosed in quotation marks. A change in speaker is usually indicated by a new paragraph, as in the following excerpt from *Huckleberry Finn*:
>
> “Ransomed? What’s that?”
>        “I don’t know. But that’s what they do. I’ve seen it in books; and so of course that’s what we’ve got to do.”
>       “But how can we do it if we don’t know what it is?”
>       “Why, blame it all, we’ve *got* to do it. Don’t I tell you it’s in the books? Do you want to go to doing different from what’s in the books, and get things all muddled up?”
>
> If one speech (usually a particularly long one) occupies more than a paragraph, opening quotation marks are needed at the beginning of each new paragraph, with a closing quotation mark placed at the end of only the final paragraph.